# how can open 2 images and 2 voice in one activity in android

Tags: android

I have an image (image 1, image 2)
I have two syllables (one voice 1, the voice 2)
I want when I open image 1 and press the button actuation audio clip 1.
And when I open image 2 and click on the button actuation audio clip 2.
I try this code

```
btprevious = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
btnext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myImage);

btprevious.setOnClickListener(this);
btnext.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
    case R.id.button1:
        i++;
        if(i==2) 
        {
            i=1; 
        }
        changeImage();
        break;

    case R.id.button2:
        i--;
        if(i==-1)
        {
            i=0; 
        }
        changeImage();
        break;
    }
}

public void changeImage()
{
    myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myImage);

    switch(i)
    {
    case 0:
        myImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.c1);
        break;

    case 1:
        myImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.c2);
        break;

    }
}

}
```

and this code of sound

```
  sound.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

         public void onClick(View v) {
             MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(Circal.this,R.raw.apple);
             player.start();
         }
     });
```

Comment: What's the issue ?

Comment: I want to work a button when pressed occupies the first sound
When press again occupies the second sound

Comment: @ArwaAli you may add a variable (boolean) or any. and change it when button is pressed first time, and again check that variable value. and decide.

Comment: let me know if you need more detail.

Comment: it will run just a once